# Why only the First Element is being added to the div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create the following HTML dynamically as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/39/)

I was trying it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/40/). When I click on the Add To swiper-wrapper Button ,  could anybody please let me know **why only the first element is being added** in this case ??

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
<input type="button" id="addtoswipperwrapper" value="Add To swiper-wrapper" />

$(document).on("click", "#addtoswipperwrapper", function () {
    var treemenudiv = $('<div class="TreeMenu" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a"></div>');
    var h3tagdata = '';
    var searchResponse = ["T1", "T2", "T3"]
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResponse.length; i++) {
        h3tagdata += '<h3>' + searchResponse[i] + '</h3>';
    }
    treemenudiv.append(h3tagdata);
    $('.swiper-wrapper').append(treemenudiv).trigger("create");;
});
```

Comment: I had this problem too earlier. My solution is place the for loop in another function. I suspect for loop consumes time and the next line has ran before completing the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place everything inside your loop. You don't need to increment the value of `h3tagdata`. secondly place the `treemendiv` inside you it will be generated and appending exact number of times as loop executes.

**EDIT:**

[**Updated Demo JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/kgm9o693/44/)

If you want to append the content only once, then you can use any way to execute the code only one. Jquery [**.one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is the best to use as its executes only once.

```
$("#addtoswipperwrapper").one("click", function () {
    var h3tagdata = '';

    var searchResponse = ["T1", "T2", "T3"];


    for (var i = 0; i < searchResponse.length; i++) {
        var treemenudiv = $('<div class="TreeMenu" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a"></div>');
        h3tagdata = '<h3>' + searchResponse[i] + '</h3>';
        treemenudiv.append(h3tagdata);
        $('.swiper-wrapper').append(treemenudiv).trigger("create");
    }
});
```

---

**[Working Demo JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/kgm9o693/42/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "#addtoswipperwrapper", function () {

   var h3tagdata = '';

    var searchResponse = ["T1", "T2", "T3"]
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResponse.length; i++) {
           var treemenudiv = $('<div class="TreeMenu" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a"></div>');
        h3tagdata = '<h3>' + searchResponse[i] + '</h3>';
        console.log(h3tagdata);
        treemenudiv.append(h3tagdata);
        console.log(treemenudiv);
        $('.swiper-wrapper').append(treemenudiv).trigger("create");
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you , but When i clcik on Button , it is appending multiple times

Comment: Do you want to append it only once if it is not exist already ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope this is exactly what you are looking for :)